# How to get last offset of a partition of a Kafka topic?

Tags: c, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am using C library (`librdkafka`) to write a Kafka consumer. I need to know the last offset of a partition of a given topic (and the lag too). I know it is possible with Python (from a similar post on Stackoverflow) but I didn't find a way to do it in C... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`query_watermark_offsets`](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/clients/librdkafka/classRdKafka_1_1Handle.html) in order to get both high and low offsets of a partition.

> `query_watermark_offsets (const std::string &topic, int32_t partition, int64_t *low, int64_t *high, int timeout_ms)=0`
>
> Query broker for low (oldest/beginning) and high (newest/end) offsets
>   for partition.
>
> Offsets are returned in *low and *high respectively.
>
> Returns `RdKafka::ERR_NO_ERROR` on success or an error code on failure.

Comment: Thanks you very much: rd_kafka_query_watermark_offsets does the trick and high offset is exactly what I need !